# Reading an integer from stdin gives strange results

Tags: c

I try to read an integer from stdin with the following C program.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int a = 0;
  read(0, &a, sizeof(int));
  printf ("a = %d\n",a);
}
```

However, I got strange results: when I input 34, I suppose the program  outputs 34, but it does 668723. Why?

Comment: 668723 is `0xA3433` is `0x0A3433` which is ASCII newline, `4`, `3` in reverse, due to endianness.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &a);`?

Comment: don't mix ascii with binary

Comment: Can you link to the documentation on `read()` which you studied to research on this?

Comment: try typing `"` then CTRL+D to get 34

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre where did I mix ascii and binary?

Comment: `read` reads bytes, it doesn't convert ascii to integers

Comment: You are mixing text input with a binary reading function.

Comment: I'm not sure it works. On windows you can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) posted in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988033/reading-an-integer-from-stdin-gives-strange-results/49988695#comment86992338_49988033):

[`read()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/read) reads *bytes* not ascii

> The read() function shall attempt to read bytes from the file

ASCII `34\n` becomes `0001010 00110100 00110011` in binary. (Or really `\n43` due to endianness)

Next `0001010 00110100 00110011` converted to decimal becomes `668723`